# SPRESENSEのQZQSMが受信できない件

Tags: spresense

SPRESENSEのリリースバージョン1.3.0を利用しているのですがgnss_atcmdを動かして暫く置いてみてもQZQSMだけ受信できていないようです。@BSSLは0x40efに、@GNSは0x29に設定しました。このexamples/gnss_atcmdを動かしてQZQSMを取得するために必要な手順が何かあるでしょうか。デベロッパーガイドの11.6.6Short message deliveryの設定が具体的にどのようなものなのか理解できず何がおかしいのかわからない状況です。
何かしらの手順があればお教え頂けるとありがたいです。そうでなければ設定が正しいかの確認方法をお教え頂けると助かります。
以上よろしくお願い致します。
追伸：config.pyの編集を見るとExample supports QZ DC report outputは*で選択されているように見えます。

Answer (score 2):

私のところでは同様の設定内容で正常に受信できています。
QZQSMだけが取得できていないということは、 EXAMPLES_GNSS_ATCMD_SUPPORT_DCREPORT が
有効になっていないことが考えられますが、追伸いただいた内容からすると問題なさそうです。
他に考えられるのはQZSSのL1S信号を正常に受信しているかどうかです。
GPGSVの中に衛星番号183/184/185/189のいずれかが含まれていること、もしくは
QZGSVの中に衛星番号55/56/57/61のいずれかが含まれていることを確認してみてください。

Comment: コメント、本当にありがとうございました。ご連絡が遅れてしまって申し訳ありません。
以下の受信状況であり４衛星（有効なのは３衛星）が受信されている模様です。
$QZGSV,1,1,04,01,72,182,26,02,03,187,,03,71,193,16,07,46,201,21*69

Comment: なおこの受信を行ったのと合わせて別のQZSS専用受信機で受信を試みましたが４秒毎に通報が受信されていましたので通報自体が出ていない時刻でもなさそうでした。

Comment: ご提示されているQZGSVセンテンスの例を解読してみると、衛星番号は01/02/03/07の4機になっており、これらはすべてL1C/A信号です。災危通報に必要なL1S信号(55/56/57/61)が含まれていないようです。

Comment: $QZGSV,2,1,05,57,75,184,45,01,67,175,45,02,06,191,39,03,75,184,44*66
$QZGSV,2,2,05,07,46,200,39,,,,,,,,,,,,*5D

Comment: 上記はQZQSMの受信に成功している場合のQZGSVセンテンス例です。L1S信号の57、L1C/A信号の01/02/03/07の合計5機になっているので2行にまたがっています。

Comment: L1S衛星番号についての情報ありがとうございました。改めて受信結果を確認したところQZGSVが２行にわたっている箇所は以下のようでした。
$QZGSV,2,1,05,61,46,201,24,01,55,169,25,02,14,195,21,03,85,185,28*6A
$QZGSV,2,2,05,07,46,201,22,,,,,,,,,,,,*56
ただ２行にわたっている回数は１行に比べると非常に少ない状況でした。場所等を変更して様子を見てみようと思います。
ご支援に深く感謝致します。